# Getting the dimensions of multidimensional arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Suppose that my function gets a two dimensional array as input and its dimensions are unknown. How can I figure them out using reflection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need reflection for this.

You can call the [`GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) method of the `Array` class and pass the dimension index.

Comment: Oooh... I saw the method in my searches and for some reason assumed it didn't accept any parameters... Guess I should've read further.
Well, thanks.